# Changing fonts in Corona SDK

Tags: fonts, lua, coronasdk

I've just started learning Lua using Corona SDK. I've tried to display a simple text, center it, and change the font to "AmericanTypewriter-Bold".

```
_screen = {
    height = display.contentHeight,
    width = display.contentWidth
}
_screen._center = {
    x = display.contentCenterX,
    y = display.contentCenterY
}

local font = "AmericanTypewriter-Bold"
local titleText = display.newText("Hello",0,0, font, 50)
titleText.x = _screen._center.x
titleText.y = _screen._center.y
```

Unfortunately, the font doesn't change. This font should only be accessible on iOS devices so I'm using iPhone 6 Plus for viewing - still the font doesn't change.

Comment: check wether the font is available
 https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/getFontNames.html

Comment: you better download that font and use it in your game.